# Как при unit-тестировании angular подключить глобальные переменные из внешних библиотек?

Tags: angularjs, yandex-maps-api, юнит-тесты

Проблема в следующем: есть приложение с подключенным API яндекс.картам. API подключается добавлением ссылки в теге script и создаёт глобальную переменную ymaps и используется примерно так:

```
ymaps.ready(init);

function init(){
    myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
        center: [55.76, 37.64],
        zoom: 15,
        controls: ['zoomControl', 'fullscreenControl']
    });       
};
```

Соответственно, тест её загрузить не может и выдаёт ошибку "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: ymaps. "
Для тестирования использую Karma + Jasmine.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно её замокать или обернуть в модуль, чтобы избежать ошибки?